# jquery message system without php how to?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, put

i took some interest in this script http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/comment-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html

and i see that the ajax calls `commentajax.php`.

what i want to do is to ignore that php, because i want to post to a json file and then get the response from the same file.

my server will use `POST` or `PUT` to put the data in the database, so there is no need for me to use php, just the syntax is killing me :)

i want to use :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://www.xxx.com/json",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
    $("ol#update").append(html);
    $("ol#update li:last").fadeIn("slow");
    document.getElementById('comment').value='';
    $("#name").focus();
    $("#flash").hide();
}
});
```

but then how would the `commentajax.php` look like?
maybe replace the php with :

```
$.getJSON('http://www.xxx.com/json' , function(data) { ... });
```

any idea helps
Thanks.

edit1:  `i have the server-side script in place`

Comment: You do realize this absolutely cannot be done without some server-side code, right?

Comment: Well, why not. You could set up your webserver to allow `PUT` write requests to a static `json` file. The problem there is that you have no mitigation against rogue clients. And your jQuery code would need to GET the file, update it, then PUT it back into the json file. Technically feasible, but the usefulness is debatable.

Comment: right, i now use `PUT` to update my database, i just got a bit confuze with this script

Comment: I sugest you to use some db with http interface (like MongoDB, CouchDB) for it instead of file. Works the same from Js perspective and it will solve a lot of problems on the start. Also there are already js libraries for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the server side scripting set up already, then what is the question again?

If you're asking how to handle the ajax call, then it's mostly a matter of looping through the JSON that you get back, and applying those values to the site in some manner.  Pseudo code:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.xxx.com/json' , function(data) { 
 for(i=0; i<data.comment.length; i++) {
   $(".commentTitle").html(data.comment[i].title);
   $(".commentBody").html(data.comment[i].text);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly:

```
because i want to post to a json file and then get the response from the same file.
```

You are going to need some server side scripting in order to 'post' to the json file.  How are you getting the data into the file.

You can 'read' the data file from the server, that's not a problem, it is a matter of getting the data into the file that you need the server side scripting for.

Comment: i have the server-side script in place, i just need to know what is the wright syntax of js